# I don't understand the object mismatch in a multithreading game

Tags: c++, multithreading, object, for-loop

I am working on a multithread game.  It has 3 classes :

- `Carte`, a map of composed of several `Case`
- `Batiment`, a ship, ships fighting each others.
- `Case`, is a basic cell of the map, and which may be linked with a `Batiment`.

Each thread control an object of Batiment, everything seems to work great, but when I try to output the game, showing the id numbers of my differents threads representing a `Batiment` in a map, it doesn't work.  Instead of printing every thread, it only prints the last `Batiment` I created in the `main.cpp`.

I am stagging for 3 days on it...

Here are my files :

**main.cpp:**

```
std::vector<Batiment> batiments;
for(int i = 0; i < nbrBatiments; i++){ //Ajout des Batiments sur le vecteur
        //Batiment temp = new Batiment(&carte, i);
        Batiment temp(&carte, i);
        batiments.push_back(temp);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < nbrBatiments; i++){
        if ((rc = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, Batiment::launcher, (void *)&batiments[i]))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: pthread_create, rc: %d\n", rc); return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
```

**Batiment.cpp:** the launcher function, I use it to pass an object to the thread :

```
void *Batiment::launcher(void *context)
{
     return static_cast<Batiment*>(context)->jouer();
}
```

**Batiment.h:** here the members of the class

```
Carte *carteInside;
static void *launcher(void *context);
int id;
void *jouer();
```

**Case.h:** here the member of the class, which is linked to an Batiment object :

```
    Batiment *batiment;
```

My `Batiment::jouer()` method is just a method which move the current object in the map and shot another object... When I "cout" the current id of the object which calls `jouer()`, where the described problem happens

**Carte.cpp:**

```
for(int i = 0; i<this->x; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<this->y; j++){
        if(this->carte[i][j].libre == false){
            printf("%d", this->carte[i][j].batiment->id);
        }
    }
}
```

**carte.h:** members of the class

```
std::vector< std::vector<Case> > carte;
```

**EDIT: constructor of `Batiment`:**

```
Batiment::Batiment(Carte *carte, int i) {
    this->carteInside = carte;
    do{
        this->x = doRand(0, carte->x);
        this->y = doRand(0, carte->y);
    }
    while(!carteInside->carte[x][y].libre);
    this->id = i;
    this->orientation = doRand(0, 3);
    this->longueur = doRand(2, 4);  
    this->vie = 2*(this->longueur)*(this->longueur);    
    carte->carte[this->x][this->y].libre = false;
    carte->carte[this->x][this->y].batiment = this;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of constructor `Batiment(Carte* pc, int n)`, please ?

Comment: Yes, I used `carte->carte[this->x][this->y].batiment = this;` to pass the object (see original post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you populate `Carte` via the constructor of `Batiment`, but using a temporary object that is destroyed making the pointer invalid:

## Why ?

In this statement you create a temporary `Batiment`:

```
   Batiment temp(&carte, i);
```

Your constructor will apparently insert a pointer to the newly created object in `Carte::carte[][]`.

Unfortunately,  you define this temporary in the block of the for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nbrBatiments; i++){ //Ajout des Batiments sur le vecteur
        Batiment temp(&carte, i);   // <=== L'instance n'existe que le temps d'une itération !! 
        ...
    }
```

So this temporary is created and destroyed  in every single iteration of this loop. So your pointer is invalid as soon as you leave the loop.

When you refer to it later, it's undefined behaviour. It's just a piece of luck that it finds any meaningful value at all.

By the way, when you pushback temp in the vector, a copy of the object will be made (same values, but still another address).

## How to solve it ?

Well, keeping the idea of your inital design,  there are several solutions.

The simplest one would be to create your Batiment on the free store:

```
 Batiment *temp = new Batiment (&carte, i);
```

The only point is that the object needs to be deleted one day somewhere.  So either you take care of this in the destructor of Carte, or you change your vecotr to keep a pointer so that you can later delete the all these objects.

The better approach would be to use `shared_ptr`, that take care by themselves of memory maangement.

Comment: Yes, but I copy the object to an Vector of Batiment in the loop : `batiments.push_back(temp);` so this isn't temporary right ?

Comment: You are right ! I tryed to put the object inside the map after I pushed_back and it worked ! So there was a adress problem... Thanks again for the solution and the advice